# IIS not serving shtml files properly, instead the browser tries to download the file

Tags: iis, windows-xp, browser, shtml

Okay, so I'm at a temporary office and they've given me a machine with XP to do dev on. Awesome.

I've set the site up in IIS and I need it to serve shtml files.

Problem is, when I browse to the shtml file, the browser tries to download the file, rather than display it properly.

I've tried a few things that I've found on other site to no avail, and now I'm just getting frustrated.

Any help?!?!

-Ev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you serving it with the correct mime type?

shtml simply use the `text/html` mime type but your IIS might not be configured to match that file extension with that mime type

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(WS.10).aspx for details on adding mime types (you didn't specify the version of IIS... those docs are for IIS 7)

Comment: Mmmm,it's IIS on XP, so I think that's IIS6. So good advice. I added the mime type but it still tries to download the file. So that didn't work, but I agree, that sounds like the problem... now, why would that not work?

In other versions of IIS I can go to Web Service Extensions and switch on SSI or something, but I don't know how to do the equivalent in xp..

Comment: see this: http://support.theplanet.com/kb/operatingsystems/microsoftwindows/iis-60-will-not-serve-my-shtml-files-how-can-i-fix I haven't tested it, but it seems to be the same problem

Comment: Ah, this is how I usually enable shtml. A quick Google told me that XP actually uses 5.1, not 6.0 as I previously stated. Thanks for the help by the way, @Jonathan

Comment: ahh, alright then. I should have checked for that. Glad you got it all sorted out

Answer (score 0):

IIS might be configured for .SHTM / .STM file extension. You can either change the extension in the iIS control panel, or rename your files.

Comment: Actually, IIS is only configured to use * through C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

This is part of the install of the CMS I'm using in this webapp. do you think this could be causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I never got this sorted. I suspect the CMS I was using did something odd. So After ****ing around with it for about a day I decided I'd wasted enough time on it and installed Apache to view the SSI files - still use IIs 5.1 for the actual site.

On the production/dev/test/stage environments, with a newer version of IIS it works fine. it was just my local machine I was having problems on.

So not solved, but I'm not losing anymore sleep/time over it!